# Get error when attempting to push app to Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku

When I try to push a python app to Heroku using the command:  "git push heroku master" I get the error, "No matching distribution found for cloud-init==19.3."  I tried a suggestion I found on here that said to remove that item from the registration.txt file, run commit and then push again, and keep doing this with the registration.txt list until getting a successful result. However, I continue to get this error regarding the cloud-init version and can't get beyond it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this issue. I emptied the requirements.txt file to only two items, flask & gunicorn. Then realized that while I ran commit & push again after the changes I wasn't running add.